# What currently-manufactured (2019) phone is most similar in form and function to a Samsung Galaxy Note 5?

Tags: android, smartphones

I have a Note 5, and it is good - but it is also definitely half broken.  I need a *new* phone, and I was hoping you all might have ideas.

Specifically, I am looking for a phone that preferably *has:*

1. a stylus
2. rectangular screen
3. 3.5mm audio out
4. at least 32GB storage
5. large screen

and *doesn't* have:

1. curved or beveled or otherwise *not flat* screen
2. software buttons
3. iOS

Waterproofing is a bonus.

I half suspect the answer to this question is "get another Note 5", although the ones I have found at this point are all refurbished and I'm not quite sure I trust them, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: If you include a stylus, the only thing you are going to find is the Note product line. But they are all curved glass now. You'll have to do some more research to decide what you want.

Comment: Well, that's just great.  This should be an answer though @SiXandSeven8ths

Comment: I don't think that really qualifies as much of an answer. However, I will say this, the Note 9 is a pretty solid device (my wife has one). The curved glass isn't really my thing either, but its not awful by any means. With a decent case, you're still able to grip the phone without touching the curved part of the screen.

Comment: why anyone ever thought a 3D curved screen was a good idea is beyond me.  :/

Comment: It looks amazing though. I almost went for it too, but opted for a different device. It'd be my first choice if my first choice weren't available.

Comment: Have you considered a 3rd party stylus? Capacitive touch screens are not exactly demanding and there are even videos how to make a DIY stylus, so it does not have to come with the phone.

Comment: "have you considered a third-party stylus": no, on account of their not having hardware/software support vis-a-vis cases and not leaving it somewhere and such.